# HTML nested min-height

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="a">
  <div id="b">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #a {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: green;
  }
  #b {
    min-height: 100%;
    background: yellow;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/otpxvb2u/

Why does the browser display green and not yellow?

Comment: Add `height:1px` to `#a` for [a work-around](http://jsfiddle.net/otpxvb2u/3/).

Comment: `#a {height:inherit;}` [also works](http://jsfiddle.net/otpxvb2u/5/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This combination simply can’t work.

Your outer element has a min-height – that means, it’s height actually depends on it’s content. If the content was larger than the 100%, then the actual height of the outer element would be more than those 100% the min-height specifies.

But now you want the inner element’s height to be a min-height of 100% as well – so the inner element would have to look for the outer element to determine its actual height, and the same thing the other way around for the outer element. That equation is just not solvable.

So you need to set an explicit height for the outer element: `height:100%`

**EDIT** pertaining to your comment:

> Any explanation for why @George's work-around works?

`height:1px` acts as a kind of “starting value” for the equation.

The inner element has a *definitive* height to start with now, `1px` – so for the outer element, the minimum of (`100%`, `height-determined-by-height-of-child-element`) can be determined now – and that will result in `100%` (of the height of the parent of that outer element, `body`), which leads to a specific pixel value as the *calculated value*.

And now the `min-height:100%` for the inner element can kick in as well – the outer element has an *effective* value in pixels now, and so the minimum of (`100% of that-pixel-value`, `1px`) can be calculated for the inner element as well, which will result in that same pixel value as the outer element has effectively.

Comment: Thanks for your very clear explanation. Any explanation for why @George's work-around works?

Comment: Yes, see my edit please. (A little too long for comment.)

Comment: FYI: Simply setting `height:inherit;` on the `#a` also works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `height` instead of `min-height`

```
#a {
    height: 100%;
    background: green;
}
#b {
    height: 100%;
    background: yellow;       
}
```

Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/otpxvb2u/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

To inherit the hight, the parent element need a height definition. So add the height attribute to the parent.

```
#a {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;        
    background: green;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stefan_wave/otpxvb2u/2/)

Answer (score 0):

or may be you can fix the  min-height in pixel

```
 #b {
    min-height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
  }
```

check the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/otpxvb2u/4/

Answer (score 0):

Provide the height to #b

```
#b {
height: 100px;
....
....
```

or

give height: 100%; to #a and #b

```
#a,#b{
height:100%;
....
....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#a
{
height:auto;
}

#b
{
height:auto;
min-height:200px;
}
```